# Preventing the white gap that appears on swiping UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I have implemented the UIPageViewController in this manner:

[image: Screenshot1]

`GalleryViewController`: is the container of the PageViewController

`PageViewController`: is the pageViewController which I added it to GalleryViewController as a subview.

`PageContentViewController`: I put in it UIImageView to be the content of the page view controller.

Everything is going well, but when I swipe between images, weird things happen. There is white gap appears upside.

[image: white gap]

The weird thing is when I finish scrolling it stretches automatically.

[image: full screen]

This is the code of `GalleryViewController`, which is the container of the PageViewController:

```
import UIKit

class PageViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var startIndex:Int = 0

var pageViewController : UIPageViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true;
    reset()
}

func reset() {
    /* Getting the page View controller */
    pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let pageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([pageContentViewController!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    println("\(startIndex) start index")
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).pageIndex!
    index++
    if(index >= Constants.Statics.images.count){
        return nil
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).pageIndex!
    if(index <= 0){
        return nil
    }
    index--
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController? {
    if((Constants.Statics.images.count == 0) || (index >= Constants.Statics.images.count)) {
        return nil
    }
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as PageContentViewController
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    return pageContentViewController
}

}
```

What can I do to prevent that stretching and the white gap on swiping?

**UPDATED:**

A strange thing has happened, I changed the pageViewController Transition Style to `Page Curl`, the problem did not appear. Sounds like it is about scrolling!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The origin of the bug is the constraints of your UIImageView.

When you begin scroll, only viewWillAppear is called, and autolayout is not yet calculated, when the scroll is finished, and view is shown, the view start calculate autolayout, and viewDidAppear happens after autolayout is completed.

you can check that by adding the code below in `PageContentViewController`

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "UpcomingGamesBg")
    println("viewDidLoad imageView Frame : \(imageView.frame) pageIndex : \(pageIndex)")
  }

  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    println("viewWillAppear imageView Frame : \(imageView.frame) pageIndex : \(pageIndex)")
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    println("viewDidAppear imageView Frame : \(imageView.frame) pageIndex : \(pageIndex)")
  }
```

And because, the layout of your imageView refer to top layout guide, and top layout guide can have different value before and after calculating autolayout, you have this bug.

So to resolve that, you can change the constraints of your image view and make them relatives to the parent view (because the pageContentViewController is like a subview and the the pagerViewController will manage the top and the bottom margin), like that  :

[image]

### [image][image]

With that you can fix this bug, but be careful you should add some contraints to your pageViewController.view

**Update**

For example to support navigationBar / TabBar, you should add some constraints in viewDidLoad (after `view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)` ):

```
      pageViewController.view.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: topLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let bottomConstaint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: bottomLayoutGuide, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageViewController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0)

    view.addConstraints([topConstraint, bottomConstaint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
```

Best regards,

Comment: my UIImageView is inside scroll view as well, i use it for zooming functionality. i did the scroll view constraint also for 0 still facing same thing

Comment: It is a big project, i will upload the files that i used for this part

Comment: while i am creating a new project to upload it on github, i found out that the problem exactly that you explained in this answer, I added same constraint that u explained for UIImageView to the container scrollView, that solved the problem!.. thank you Hamza

Answer (score 2):

The auto stretching is because the ImageView instances are not constrained to aspect fit. In your `PageContentViewController`, specify `contentMode` value for your images to fix the issue. For example:

```
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: still stretching after i set up the content mode to scal aspect fit

Answer (score 2):

Check definitely example here: https://github.com/dimpiax/UIPageViewControllerScrolling

But if you want to remove empty blank on swipe, you can remove bounce, for example:

```
for value in view.subviews {
    if let scrollView = value as? UIScrollView {
        scrollView.bounces = false
    }
}
```

Comment: the content of my viewPageController is ViewController that contains scroll view, and inside the scroll view there is UIImageView, to provide zoomable uiimage, so that i already disabled the bouncing, the problem happens somewhere in the pageViewController

Comment: Need to disable inside UIPageViewController

Comment: Thank you, this is pretty helpful actually, but you need to update to newest swift now.

Comment: @windsound I wanted to update commonly approach of it. But now will also update it under Swift 2, also. Check there later today.

Comment: @windsound there is new version, also with configuration where is disabling of bounce

Answer (score 1):

So it appears that the view's frame is not correct before the animation takes place. Try setting up the frame before it starts to come on screen. Something like:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).pageIndex!
    if(index <= 0){
        return nil
    }
    index--

    // Setting up the new view's frame
    var newVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
    newVC.view.frame = self.pageViewController.view.bounds
    return newVC
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, now it shows the image in a smaller bounds, even smaller than before, and it stretches more as well

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried those? You should select your content view **controller** first. Note: click on the controller, not the view

1. uncheck Adjust Scroll View Insets
2. uncheck Under Top Bars
3. uncheck Under Bottom Bars

[image]

Comment: I setup the pageViewController inside another view controller as an outlet. I set your snippet up in the viewController that contains the pageViewController. but it did not work still

Comment: I saw that in your code. I want you to make this setting with PageContentViewController in the storyboard. The page view controller's child controllers are often auto resized during swiping. That is why we need to make this setting.

Comment: There is strange thing has happened, I changed the pageViewController Transition Style to page Curl, the problem did not appear, so it is about scrolling !

Comment: Is it possible you share your project on github so I can reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Look like a layout issue.

Since `UIPageViewController` with `.Scroll` type use a `UIScrollView` to make it,

try to add `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` to your `viewDidLoad`

If it doesn't work, try to remove `self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true`

And if it doesn't work again, please provide a demo project, so I can figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Set imageView's contentMode to AspectFill ...

Comment: Can you elaborate some more?

Comment: i tried all contentMode possibilities and did not work