# UIPageViewController's child ViewController acting weird

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I have a `UIPageViewController` (parent) managing multiple `UIViewControllers` (children). Children VC only have 1 `UIImageView` with the the following constraints: `0 px` to left and right, `0 px` to **Top layout guide**, 20px to **bottom layout guide**

When I change page in `Forward` direction, it behaves correctly. When I change page in `Backward` direction, said `UIImageView` seems to cover the whole space (similar to what it would look like if it had no constraint) during the transition animation, and when the transition is done, it corrects  it's position.

Long story short, when going flipping page backwards, the image appears bigger during animation, and then it changes to the correct size. Why is this happening?

PS: I created a boilerplate "Page based application" and it doesn't happen

**Edit:** My storyboard nest a couple of VC like this: `TabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIPageViewController`. The VCs hosted by pageVC are added dynamically in code.

I already tried setting the UIImageView constraints to the parents and I noticed 2 things:

1. The top part of the image is being hidden by the navigation bar.
2. The problem persist

Any ideas?

**Edit: 2**

My `NavigationController` host a VC that **pushes** `UIPageViewController` (maybe this is not how it's supposed to be done?) , so I don't really "add" the UIPageViewController through code. I add it's children through code. Here's a SS

[image]

Moreover, the children are just a `UIViewController` with a `UIImageView` with `0` constraint to the container view (not the layout guide), so it covers the whole space.

Comment: Don't use top/bottom layout guides. Use constraints relative to the superview instead.

Comment: you can find here the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/29589531/2477632

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone - Preventing the white gap appears on swiping UIPageViewController - swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198160/iphone-preventing-the-white-gap-appears-on-swiping-uipageviewcontroller-swif)

Comment: The problem still persists :(  Maybe I am doing something wrong? read my edit please

Comment: can you add please the code used to add pageViewController, also the contraints of your UIImageView ? thanks

Comment: OK, I will try to reproduce the bug, and I will get back to you as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the frame of the of UIPageViewController, when we instantiate it from the storyboard the view frame is equal to the screen frame (without the topLayoutGuide and bottomLayoutGuide) and also the childs view controller take the same frame...

So to fix that we have two solutions :

**The first solution**

Add the topLayoutGuide and the bottomLayoutGuide constraints to the imageView, but with this solution we get some problems with animation, because the frame is calculated only when the page is completely shown (you can find more details here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29589531/2477632)

**The second solution**

1- Instantiate differently the MagazinePagesViewController :  Create
    MagazinePagesViewController with UIViewController super class (and
    not UIPageViewController)

2- Add programmatically a pageViewController

```
let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.Scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.Horizontal, options: nil)
pageViewController.view.frame = view.frame //add also some constraints if needed to support rotation
view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
addChildViewController(pageViewController)
pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

If needed I can upload  the sample code with these two solutions.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm gonna try this, can I get the sample code you were talking about, thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the second solution, and it is still happening. I changed the segue to Modal, and it doesn't happen, so I think the TOP constraint needs to make consider navigation bar Height, the thing is I don't know if I should hardcode the value or if there's something similar to Top Layout Guide to do this?

Comment: You are right, for the second solution we must add constraints to work, for your question, the Top Layout Guide is good :) you can find here the sample (with constraints for the second solution) http://we.tl/uLQSBCrNrS, I will update my answer soon. hope that helps

Comment: I love you ;-;  thanks a lot, The second solution worked. I think what I was missing was the constraints you set during viewDidLoad()

Comment: @HamzaGhazouani can you re-post the code? use gist or something else that doesn't expire, thanks in advance!